# Sum column every n column in a data frame R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, sum

I have a `df(A)` with 10 column and 300 row. I need to sum every two column, between them, in this way:

```
A[,1]+A[,2] = # first result
A[,3]+A[,4] = # second result
A[,5]+A[,6]= # third result
....
A[,9]+A[,10] # last result
```

The expected final result is a new dataframe with 5 column and 300 row.
Any way to do this? with `tapply` or loop `for`? 
I know that i can try with the upon example, but i'm looking for a fast method
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use `sapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(expr=rnorm(100),n = 10))
sapply(seq(1,9,by=2),function(i) rowSums(df[,i:(i+1)]))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without *apply loops.

Sample data:

```
df <- head(iris[-5])
df
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Now you can use vector recycling of a logicals:

```
df[c(TRUE,FALSE)] + df[c(FALSE,TRUE)]
#  Sepal.Length Petal.Length
#1          8.6          1.6
#2          7.9          1.6
#3          7.9          1.5
#4          7.7          1.7
#5          8.6          1.6
#6          9.3          2.1
```

Comment: This is adding the first group of columns to the second instead of what's described above

Comment: It's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit cryptic but I it should be fast. We add each column to the adjacent column. Then delete the unnecessary results with `c(T,F)` which recycles through odd columns:

```
(A[1:(ncol(A)-1)] + A[2:ncol(A)])[c(T,F)]
```